# Elasticsearch terms with space returns no results

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to match exact text irrespective of case. What I want works with

```
    GET elastic_org/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "registeredName": {
        "minimum_should_match": "100%",
        "query": "prop org"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the library I use https://github.com/olivere/elastic/, does not support minimum should match

I'm trying with `term` query

```
GET elastic_org/_search
{
  "query": {
   "term": {
     "registeredName": "Prop org" //also tried prop org
   }
  }
}
```

I don't get any results. I tried the above query for a word `nospace` and I get results.

How do I get exact matches without it being case sensitive and with space?

Index mapping:

```
{
  "elastic_org" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
       
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        
        "registeredName" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`case_insensitive`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#term-field-params) param along with the terms query. This parameter was introduced in elasticsearch version 7.10.0

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "registeredName.keyword": {
        "value": "prop org",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

[Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#term-field-params) returns documents that match exactly with the search term. When using a term query, the `text` type fields should not be used.

Based on your index mapping, you need to add .keyword to the `registeredName` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `registeredName` field).

**Update 2:**

If you don't want to use the `case_insensitive` parameter, you can use the lowercase filter. This will ensure that all the terms are lowercase, before indexing and searching

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "registeredName": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "registeredName": "Prop org"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "registeredName": "prop org"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67716203",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "registeredName": "Prop org"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: thanks for answering. it's not the case part.. I don't get results even if I search with proper case for a word with space in it. Like I said in question, word `nospace` gives result but `Prop org` does not give result(I'm using exact case as stored)

Comment: @Abhi can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: @Abhi according to your mapping, you need to use `"registeredName.keyword"` in the term query. Please try this and let me know if this worked ?

Comment: is there any way to make it work without the `case_insensitive: true`

Comment: @Abhi yes there is, but you need to then make changes in index mapping. Should I share the new index mapping for the same? And, which version of elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: @Abhi and are you getting the search result now, with proper case and space ?

Comment: yes. I am getting it, but can you share what changes to make in mapping. I'm using 7.10.0

Comment: hey.. can you tell me how I can do this using https://github.com/olivere/elastic .. I don't see any option to search using keywords and the case insensitive option. I couldn't find any example in his _test.go files either

Comment: @Abhi I am not quite familiar with the elasticsearch client of Go, but I think you should ask a separate question, (regarding implementing the `keyword` type field in Go), so that other folks can help you :-)